# Convert text format to date in mySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have a CSV file I imported into mySQL. One of the columns has dates in it but the data type for it in mySQL is 'text'.

How can I convert it to a date format?
Example dates in the column:

```
2/2/2012
7/23/2011
11/27/2011
```

I've tried using

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(latest_launch,'%m,%d,%Y')
FROM cars;
```

But the output gives me a blank column.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are you using commas in the format string instead of slash? It has to match the format in the column.

Comment: Oh got it. Thanks for that. I switched to '%m/%d/%Y' but the output I get is now 2012-09-28 which is good. Ordering on this new column isn't working still. Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest looking at the 'CAST()' function,

Your solution might look something like this:

```
    SELECT CAST(<text> AS date);
```

Where  is the text you want to make into the date type.

If you want to change an entire column try something like this:

```
    SELECT CAST(<column_name> AS DATE)
    FROM Table
```

Where <column_name> is the entire column you are trying to convert to the date type.

I hope this was helpful! Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I tried the CAST way but it the output is a blank column. All records in the column show as 'null'

Comment: You can't use `CAST` if the date isn't in the format that MySQL recognizes.

Comment: Which is `YYYY-MM-DD`, not `MM/DD/YYYY`.